# border image on a gride view

Tags: android, android-gridview

I had a gridview like this

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/aldiko_shelf_background"
android:columnWidth="40sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:paddingLeft="20sp"
android:paddingRight="20sp"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="30sp" />
```

[image]

I want to add a image as a border of the total grid and want to add another image between two row which will looks like this

[image]

Comment: Cool. And your question is?

Comment: I want to add a image as a border of the total grid and want to add another image between two row which will looks like this  **But don't know who to add this border image and row bellow image**

Comment: Why you cant try this with a ListView ?

Comment: I need to make each and every image clickable in case of list view how can I make clickable each and every iamge in a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question there are two ways to do this ,a simple one and a not so simple one

First ,the simple one-> try putting a backgound image  eg:a book shelf image

Second,->you can modify your rows view in you XML to have an image in-between you images

I think that what you need is a bookshelf type layout try this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-dynamic-shelfview-in-Android)

Comment: any example for that second one Please don't down vote me I am new on android

Comment: What you can do is that first edit the image layout by putting another image(a line image) at the bottom of you grid image.Next put padding to you grid imageso that d line image exceeds the grid image'd width.Now it should work.

Comment: how to put another image inside in a grid view

Comment: you will be using another layout which has the image to be displayed in that grid view

Comment: I have this grid view

 `<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/aldiko_shelf_background"
android:columnWidth="40sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:paddingLeft="20sp"
android:paddingRight="20sp"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="30sp" />`

How to add image on top please tell I am new on android don't down vote me

Comment: I have edited my answer with a link , go through that,I think thats what you need

Comment: I don't know what I asked wrong why people down voted me by the way thank you